# Convert SQL Server 2008 database to SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008

Convert SQL Server 2008 database to SQL Server 2005. Any solution please?

Comment: Why downgrade when you can set the compatibility level...

Comment: I need it because i have a client that have sqlserver2005 and i can't change it.

Comment: I think @OMG Ponies is suggesting that you set your 2008 databases (which it sounds like you control) to be 2005 compatible so effectively everyone is at 2005...

Comment: Hey I have a SqlServer2008 Database and i want to port it to my client computer that have SqlServer2005.got it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can script your 2008 database to create the database objects and insert data, then run that script on the 2005 instance.  You might have to temporarily disable foreign keys to get some of the inserts to work.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to set the compatibility level of your 2008 SQL Servers to be 2005 (so that you are effectively saying that they are all 2005), you can use the `SET COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL` command to do this...[MSDN link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510680.aspx)

Using there example, you would run this on your 2008 databases:

```
ALTER DATABASE database_name -- change me!
SET COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL = 90 -- set to sql server 2005 compatibility level
```

Comment: Hey I really need to convert my database to sqlserver 2005.

Comment: @LightWing, as far as I understand (and it's not a lot) as long as you are NOT using "2008" features, you can just script your 2008 database into 2005...or use a SQL Schema comparison (like redgate sql compare) to move the schema from 2008 to 2005...again, unless you are using 2008 features, everything you've got is backwards compatible already...